# Ancient Indian sites, where Jataka stories are illustrated through sculpture and painting?

Tags: art, jataka

I know that many Jataka stories are illustrated, through sculpture and painting, in ancient Indian sites like Sanchi, Bharhut, Ajanta etc. I have found some of them in various books and websites. What I need is a comprehensive list of such illustrations. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

There's [The Illustrated Jataka & Other Stories of the Buddha](https://web.archive.org/web/20070607011401/http://ignca.nic.in/jatak.htm)

Some are also covered in this [documentary](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lWAj22H4qWg)

A simple comprehensive list can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jataka_tales#List_of_J%C4%81takas)